# Stripe: can't change plan for authenticated 3DS card?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm trying to allow customers to change their Stripe plan via the API, but 3D Secure test cards are failing even though they should be authenticated for future use.

My API call is as follows:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->update(
  $subscription_id, [
  'items' => [
    [
      'id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->id,
      'price' => $new_plan_id,
    ],
  ],
]);
```

This works absolutely fine with a standard card number (e.g. 4242 4242 4242 4242)

However for 3DS cards it returns a 402 error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "subscription_payment_intent_requires_action",
    "message": "Payment for this subscription requires additional user action before it can be completed successfully. Payment can be completed using the PaymentIntent associated with `subscription.latest_invoice`. Additional information is available here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#requires-action",
    "type": "card_error"
    }
}
```

I'm using test card numbers which require authentication the first time (which is done when the subscription is created), but should succeed subsequent times according to this page https://stripe.com/docs/testing.

I've also tried the Javascript route as an alternative, in order to check the response of the API call and then trigger the stripe.ConfirmCardPayment() routine if authentication is required, but the fatal PHP error kills the script before it even gets to that point.

Any ideas how I could resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which card specifically are you using? What is the exact flow you're using for the initial setup?

If you're talking about the [3155 card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards), you need to explicitly set it up for future use with either a [Setup Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) or [using `setup_future_usage` with a payment intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment#web-submit-payment). It is *not* automatically set up for future usage simply by authenticating the first time.

You may wish to use the 0446 card to simulate this setup, but I encourage you to ensure you've got the implementation ready for real world scenarios by actually going through the setup flow.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried 3155 and 0446 but both gave me the same result. The flow for initial setup is almost identical to the [docs example](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price) for fixed price subscriptions: create the payment method, attach to customer, create subscription. When I inspect the customer's cards in dashboard, it does look like a Setup Intent was applied succesfully even without using it explicitly in my flow?

Comment: Are you making sure you mark the payment as off-session? When paying off-session, you shouldn't be expected to handle `requires_authentication` and flow through 3DS since the customer is not present. Instead, the payment should revert to `requires_payment_method` status and you'd have you customer come on session later and supply payment info + authentication if needed.

Comment: I've now set `off_session` to true and that's worked for a 3DS card, thanks. My customer is actually on session for the upgrade process - I was a bit confused about how to initiate the payment/authentication flow for an upgrade since I can't find any examples. I suppose I could now handle the payment intent status and send them to the Stripe hosted page to pay the invoice if needed?

Comment: Additional point: needed to set `payment_behavior` to `allow_incomplete` in order to avoid the 402 card error and handle the payment intent status.

Comment: Ah great that you got it working. To offer a correction: you should _not_ mark the payment as off-session if your customer is present in your app/site. Using allow_incomplete for an upgrade is the right approach, and if the payment requires authentication you handle that with the `latest_invoice.payment_intent` with client authentication with your customer.